# ¿Por qué al crear un excel en Android studio con Apache Poi usando HSSFWorkbook no sale error pero al cambiarlo por XSSFWorkbook si?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apache-poi

En mi app movil estoy usando la libreria Apache Poi y generando un excel con HSSFWorkbook() esto funciona muy bien, ahora quiero cambiar a XSSFWorkbook pero me sale este error: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found, leí algunas paginas y decia que debo poner en el gradel implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0' pero tampoco funciono.
En relidad quiero hacer este cambio de formato porque al abrir los excel siempre necesita internet para convertir el formato y además no me esta funcionando el style.setWrapText(true) y creo que es por esta conversión que hace.
Este es mi codigo para los excel:

```
public void crearExelPorOperador(List<Reporte> listReportes){
    String[] actividadesM =  context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.combo_tiposOperaciones);
    String[] actividadesPrincipales =  context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.combo_tiposOperacionesPrinciapales);
    String[] actividadesSecundarias =  context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.combo_tiposOperacionesSecundarias);
    Workbook wb= new HSSFWorkbook();
    Map<String, CellStyle> styles= createStyles(wb);
    Sheet sheet= wb.createSheet("Informe");
    sheet.setFitToPage(true);
    sheet.setHorizontallyCenter(true);

    //title row
    String rango;
    int nRow=0;
    int nCell=0;
    Row titleRow = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    titleRow.setHeightInPoints(20);
    Cell titleCell = titleRow.createCell(nCell);
    titleCell.setCellValue("Informe General por Operador");
    titleCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("title"));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow, //last row  (0-based)
            0, //first column (0-based)
            actividadesM.length+7 //last column  (0-based)
    ));
    //Datos
    //nombre de la empresa
    nRow=nRow+1;
    Row row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(nCell);
    cell.setCellValue("Empresa: ");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left1"));
    rango="$A$"+(nRow+1)+":$B$"+(nRow+1);
    sheet.addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress.valueOf(rango));
    nRow=nRow+1;
    cell = row.createCell(nRow);
    cell.setCellValue("Holcim Ecuador");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left"));


    //fecha
    row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    cell = row.createCell(nCell);
    cell.setCellValue("Fecha: ");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left1"));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow, //last row  (0-based)
            0, //first column (0-based)
            1 //last column  (0-based)
    ));


    cell = row.createCell(nRow);
    cell.setCellValue(editFechadesde.getText().toString()+" - "+editFechahasta.getText().toString());
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left"));

    nRow=nRow+1;

    //fecha
    row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    cell = row.createCell(nCell);
    cell.setCellValue("Actividades Prinpales:");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left1"));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow, //last row  (0-based)
            0, //first column (0-based)
            2 //last column  (0-based)
    ));
    int i=0;
    for(String n:actividadesPrincipales){
        i=i+1;
        nRow=nRow+1;
        row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
        cell = row.createCell(nCell);
        cell.setCellValue(i);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_leftamarillo"));
        cell = row.createCell(nCell+1);
        cell.setCellValue(n);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left"));

    }
    nRow=nRow+1;

    row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    cell = row.createCell(nCell);
    cell.setCellValue("Actividades Secundarias:");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left1"));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow, //last row  (0-based)
            0, //first column (0-based)
            2 //last column  (0-based)
    ));

    for(String n:actividadesSecundarias){
        i=i+1;
        nRow=nRow+1;
        row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
        cell = row.createCell(nCell);
        cell.setCellValue(i);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_leflime"));

        cell = row.createCell(nCell+1);
        cell.setCellValue(n);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("item_left"));


    }





    //titulo

    nRow=nRow+3;
    nCell=nCell+1;


    row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    cell = row.createCell(nCell);
    cell.setCellValue("Operadores");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));

    for (int n = (nCell+1); n < (nCell+3); n++) {
        cell = row.createCell(n);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));
    }



    cell = row.createCell(nCell+3);
    cell.setCellValue("Actividades");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));

    for (int n = (nCell+4); n < (nCell+actividadesM.length+5); n++) {
        cell = row.createCell(n);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));
    }


    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow+1, //last row  (0-based)
            1, //first column (0-based)
            3 //last column  (0-based)
    ));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow, //last row  (0-based)
            4, //first column (0-based)
            actividadesM.length+5 //last column  (0-based)
    ));

    cell = row.createCell(nCell+actividadesM.length+5);
    cell.setCellValue("Total");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow+1, //last row  (0-based)
            actividadesM.length+6, //first column (0-based)
            actividadesM.length+6 //last column  (0-based)
    ));

    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));

    nRow=nRow+1;
    int index=0;
    row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    for (int n = (nCell+3); n < (nCell+actividadesPrincipales.length+3); n++) {
        cell = row.createCell(n);
        cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(index+1));
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAmarillo"));
        index=index+1;
    }

    cell = row.createCell(nCell+3+actividadesPrincipales.length);
    cell.setCellValue("T.P.");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));
    for (int n = (nCell+4+actividadesPrincipales.length); n < (nCell+actividadesSecundarias.length+4+actividadesPrincipales.length); n++) {
        cell = row.createCell(n);
        cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(index+1));
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerLime"));
        index=index+1;
    }

    cell = row.createCell(nCell+4+actividadesPrincipales.length+actividadesSecundarias.length);
    cell.setCellValue("T.S.");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));


    //contenido
    nRow=nRow+1;
    String[] operadores =  context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.combo_nombresOperadores);

    List<sumaInformeOperador> listaOperadores=GetDataInformeporoperador(listReportes,asListString(operadores),context);
    List<Double> sumasActividadesPrinpales=new ArrayList<>();
    Double totalTodasPrincipales=0.0, totalTodasSecundarias=0.0;
    for(String n:actividadesPrincipales){
        sumasActividadesPrinpales.add(0.0);
    }
    List<Double> sumasActividadesSecundarias=new ArrayList<>();
    for(String n:actividadesSecundarias){
        sumasActividadesSecundarias.add(0.0);
    }


    for(sumaInformeOperador operador:listaOperadores){
        row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
        cell = row.createCell(nCell);
        cell.setCellValue(operador.getNombreOperador());
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell"));

        for (int n = (nCell+1); n < (nCell+3); n++) {
            cell = row.createCell(n);
            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell"));
        }
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
                nRow, //first row (0-based)
                nRow, //last row  (0-based)
                1, //first column (0-based)
                3 //last column  (0-based)
        ));
        int index2=0;
        double totalPrincipales=0.0;
        for (int n = (nCell+3); n < (nCell+actividadesPrincipales.length+3); n++) {
            cell = row.createCell(n);
            double total= 0.0;

           int posicion=indexActividadeenSuma(operador.getListaactividades(),actividadesPrincipales[index2]);
            if (posicion!=-1){
                total=operador.getListaactividades().get(posicion).getHoras();
            }
            totalPrincipales=totalPrincipales+total;

            BigDecimal bdtotal = new BigDecimal(total).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            int valtotal = (int) bdtotal.doubleValue();


            cell.setCellValue(valtotal);
            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell"));
            sumasActividadesPrinpales.set(index2,sumasActividadesPrinpales.get(index2)+total);
            index2=index2+1;
        }
        BigDecimal bdprinciaples = new BigDecimal(totalPrincipales).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        int valprinciaples = (int) bdprinciaples.doubleValue();
        cell = row.createCell(nCell+3+actividadesPrincipales.length);
        cell.setCellValue(valprinciaples);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell"));
        int index3=0;
        double totalSecundaria=0.0;
        for (int n = (nCell+4+actividadesPrincipales.length); n < (nCell+actividadesSecundarias.length+4+actividadesPrincipales.length); n++) {
            cell = row.createCell(n);
            double total= 0.0;

            int posicion=indexActividadeenSuma(operador.getListaactividades(),actividadesSecundarias[index3]);
            if (posicion!=-1){
                total=operador.getListaactividades().get(posicion).getHoras();
            }
            totalSecundaria=totalSecundaria+total;
            BigDecimal bdtotal = new BigDecimal(total).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            int valtotal = (int) bdtotal.doubleValue();
            cell.setCellValue(valtotal);
            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell"));
            sumasActividadesSecundarias.set(index3,sumasActividadesSecundarias.get(index3)+total);
            index3=index3+1;
        }


        BigDecimal bdtotal = new BigDecimal(totalSecundaria).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        int valtotal = (int) bdtotal.doubleValue();
        cell = row.createCell(nCell+4+actividadesPrincipales.length+actividadesSecundarias.length);
        cell.setCellValue(valtotal);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell"));
        cell = row.createCell(nCell+actividadesM.length+5);
        BigDecimal bdtotaltotal = new BigDecimal(totalPrincipales+totalSecundaria).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        int valtotaltotal = (int) bdtotaltotal.doubleValue();
        cell.setCellValue(valtotaltotal);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));





        nRow=nRow+1;
    }
    row = sheet.createRow(nRow);
    cell = row.createCell(nCell);
    cell.setCellValue("Total");
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));

    for (int n = (nCell+1); n < (nCell+3); n++) {
        cell = row.createCell(n);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));
    }
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
            nRow, //first row (0-based)
            nRow, //last row  (0-based)
            1, //first column (0-based)
            3 //last column  (0-based)
    ));
    int index4=0;
    for (int n = (nCell+3); n < (nCell+actividadesPrincipales.length+3); n++) {
        cell = row.createCell(n);
        BigDecimal bdtotaltotal = new BigDecimal(sumasActividadesPrinpales.get(index4)).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        int valtotaltotal = (int) bdtotaltotal.doubleValue();
        cell.setCellValue(valtotaltotal);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAmarillo"));
        index4=index4+1;
    }
    for(Double n:sumasActividadesPrinpales){
        totalTodasPrincipales=totalTodasPrincipales+n;
    }

    cell = row.createCell(nCell+3+actividadesPrincipales.length);
    BigDecimal bdtotaltotal = new BigDecimal(totalTodasPrincipales).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    int valtotaltotal = (int) bdtotaltotal.doubleValue();
    cell.setCellValue(valtotaltotal);
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));


    int index5=0;
    for (int n = (nCell+4+actividadesPrincipales.length); n < (nCell+actividadesSecundarias.length+4+actividadesPrincipales.length); n++) {
        cell = row.createCell(n);
        BigDecimal bdtotalS = new BigDecimal(sumasActividadesSecundarias.get(index5)).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        int valtotalS = (int) bdtotalS.doubleValue();
        cell.setCellValue(valtotalS);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerLime"));
        index5=index5+1;
    }
    for(Double n:sumasActividadesSecundarias){
        totalTodasSecundarias=totalTodasSecundarias+n;
    }
    cell = row.createCell(nCell+4+actividadesPrincipales.length+actividadesSecundarias.length);
    BigDecimal bdtotalS = new BigDecimal(totalTodasSecundarias).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    int valtotalS = (int) bdtotalS.doubleValue();
    cell.setCellValue(valtotalS);
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));
    cell = row.createCell(nCell+5+actividadesPrincipales.length+actividadesSecundarias.length);
    BigDecimal bdtotalSP = new BigDecimal(totalTodasSecundarias+totalTodasPrincipales).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    int valtotalSP = (int) bdtotalSP.doubleValue();
    cell.setCellValue(valtotalSP);
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("headerAzul"));






    //creacion del documento

    String nombreFile= "InformeGeneralPorOperador.xls";
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),nombreFile);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(outputStream);
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Reporte generado correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String[] mailto = {correo};
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context,
                "com.example.operacionesmteriasprimas", //(use your app signature + ".provider" )
                file);

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Reporte de horas de las actividades realizadas "+editFechadesde.getText().toString()+" - "+editFechahasta.getText().toString());
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Fecha de reporte:  "+editFechadesde.getText().toString()+" - "+editFechahasta.getText().toString()+".\nTipo: General por operador"+".\nAtentamente HolcimQuarry.");
        emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));


    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"NO OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}

private static Map<String, CellStyle> createStyles(Workbook wb){
    Map<String, CellStyle> styles = new HashMap<>();
    CellStyle style;
    Font titleFont = wb.createFont();
    titleFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)18);
    titleFont.setBold(true);
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFont(titleFont);
    styles.put("title", style);

    Font itemFont = wb.createFont();
    itemFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
    itemFont.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFont(titleFont);
    style.setFont(itemFont);
    styles.put("item_left", style);

    Font itemresFont = wb.createFont();
    itemresFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
    itemresFont.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
    itemresFont.setBold(true);
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFont(itemresFont);
    styles.put("item_left1", style);


    Font itemFontcenter = wb.createFont();
    itemFontcenter.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
    itemFontcenter.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFont(titleFont);
    style.setFont(itemFontcenter);
    styles.put("item_leftamarillo", style);



    Font itemFontcenterlime = wb.createFont();
    itemFontcenterlime.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
    itemFontcenterlime.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFont(titleFont);
    style.setFont(itemFontcenterlime);
    styles.put("item_leflime", style);



    Font monthFont = wb.createFont();
    monthFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
    monthFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFont(monthFont);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    styles.put("header", style);


    Font monthFont2 = wb.createFont();
    monthFont2.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
    monthFont2.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
    //monthFont2.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setFont(monthFont2);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    styles.put("header2", style);





    Font headerFont = wb.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFont(headerFont);

    styles.put("headerAzul", style);



    Font headerFont2 = wb.createFont();
    headerFont2.setBold(true);
    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFont(headerFont2);

    styles.put("headerAmarillo", style);


    Font headerFont3 = wb.createFont();
    headerFont3.setBold(true);
    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFont(headerFont3);
    styles.put("headerLime", style);


    Font cellFont = wb.createFont();
    cellFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
    style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setFont(cellFont);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    styles.put("cell", style);
    return styles;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968735/using-com-bea-xml-stream-package-on-android), es posible que requieras incluir

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
```

en el archivo de configuración gradle. Aunque otros extienden la solución y usan

```
implementation  'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0',
implementation  'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
```

y fijan `multiDexEnabled true` en el defaultConfig.

Otros indican que, de acuerdo a la documentación, hay que excluir alguna dependencia que entra en conflicto (stax-api)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12') {
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    }
}
```